# Is there a typeclass that changes the shape of a hierarchy?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I'm working with some hierarchical data, a contrived example here:

```
data Item a =
    Leaf a
    | ListItems [Item a]
    | DoubleItem (Item a) (Item a)
    | TripleItem (Item a) (Item a) (Item a)
```

I find myself often writing code like this:

```
removeDoubles :: Item a -> Item a
removeDoubles x@(Leaf _) = x
removeDoubles (ListItems xs) = ListItems $ removeDoubles <$> xs
removeDoubles (DoubleItem x y) = ListItems [removeDoubles x, removeDoubles y]
removeDoubles (TripleItem x y z) = TripleItem (removeDoubles x) (removeDoubles y) (removeDoubles z)

removeTriples :: Item a -> Item a
removeTriples x@(Leaf _) = x
removeTriples (ListItems xs) = ListItems $ removeTriples <$> xs
removeTriples (DoubleItem x y) = DoubleItem (removeTriples x) (removeTriples y)
removeTriples (TripleItem x y z) = ListItems [removeDoubles x, removeDoubles y, removeDoubles z]
```

There's obviously some overlap here between these two functions, and this approach is also not very robust if I start adding more constructors to `Item`. Is there some typeclass I should be using that would help reduce this repetition? I'm imaginging something like:

```
removeDoubles :: Item a -> Item a
removeDoubles (DoubleItem x y) = ListItems [removeDoubles x, removeDoubles y]
removeDoubles x = traverseHierarchy removeDoubles x
```

`Functor`, `Traversable` etcetera seem to be designed around changing the type of `a`, whereas I'm less interested in mapping `a -> something` and more interested in changing the shape of this hierarchy.

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for a *catamorphism*. With more formality and library tooling, the idea below can be generalized and also automated (more on that at the end of this answer). For your specific task, the code that could be automatically generated is similar to

```
data Item a =
  Leaf a
  | ListItems [Item a]
  | DoubleItem (Item a) (Item a)
  | TripleItem (Item a) (Item a) (Item a)

cata :: (a -> b) -- Leaf
     -> ([b] -> b) -- ListItems
     -> (b -> b -> b) -- DoubleItem
     -> (b -> b -> b -> b) -- TripleItem
     -> Item a
     -> b
cata leaf list double triple = go
  where go (Leaf x) = leaf x
        go (ListItems xs) = list (map go xs)
        go (DoubleItem x y) = double (go x) (go y)
        go (TripleItem x y z) = triple (go x) (go y) (go z)
```

Here `cata` is generalizing the idea of recursively folding over the structure, and has nothing to do specifically with modifying the hierarchy, for example by removing doubles. But you can use this general machinery to achieve both of your specific goals easily, and without repetition or explicit recursion:

```
removeDoubles = cata Leaf ListItems lift TripleItem
  where lift x y = ListItems [x, y]

removeTriples = cata Leaf ListItems DoubleItem lift
  where lift x y z = ListItems [x, y, z]
```

`cata` is part of a larger family of concepts called "recursion schemes". I'm sure there are numerous articles attempting to explain these concepts, but [An Introduction to Recursion Schemes](https://blog.sumtypeofway.com/posts/introduction-to-recursion-schemes.html) is one I liked. The Haskell library implementing these concepts, including automatic generation of the `cata` function for your types, is [`recursion-schemes`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes). (Really it doesn't generate `cata`; it generates typeclass instances for your type that allow you to use its predefined `cata` function, and many more)

---

To use the `cata` implementation in `recursion-schemes` instead of a bespoke implementation for your type, we need several GHC extensions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor, DeriveFoldable, DeriveTraversable -#}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell, TypeFamilies #-}

import Data.Functor.Foldable.TH (makeBaseFunctor)
import Data.Functor.Foldable (cata, embed)

data Item a =
  Leaf a
  | ListItems [Item a]
  | DoubleItem (Item a) (Item a)
  | TripleItem (Item a) (Item a) (Item a)

makeBaseFunctor ''Item
```

`makeBaseFunctor` uses Template Haskell to define a new type `ItemF`, based on `Item` but more general, called its "base functor". Its constructors are similar, but have names suffixed with `F`, and the fields that (in `Item`) recursively contain an `Item` have a more general type, whose details I won't go into.

Finally we're ready to implement your `removeDoubles` function with the minimum of detail: only describe the broad idea and let recursion-schemes do the rest of the work. Note that this is even less duplication than you hoped for in your question: the recursive calls to `removeDoubles` are all made implicit, and we can just specify what to do with a single level of the hierarchy.

```
removeDoubles :: Item a -> Item a
removeDoubles = cata go
  where go (DoubleItemF x y) = ListItems [x, y]
        go x = embed x
```

This version of `cata`, instead of taking four separate functions for the four constructors of `Item`, takes one function, and passes that function an `ItemF` argument, which can be pattern-matched similarly to an `Item`.

We match the `DoubleItemF` first, and do the "special" work there. Then in the catch-all clause afterwards, we simply use `embed` to convert the `ItemF` argument back to an `Item` without further modification. In both clauses, the `x` and `y` arguments we received have already been recursively handled by `cata` before we see them, so there's no need to do anything to their internals.

Comment: Apologies for the late response and thank you, I had seen the term "catamorphism" while googling on this topic and it looks like that is what I need. The "introduction to recursion schemes" article you link to is excellent.